# Unable to access gitlab web UI after upgrading to 14.12

Tags: gitlab, passenger

I have gitlab omnibus install on a linux debian server.  Yesterday, the installation was upgraded to 14.12 (from 14.11) - and now I'm unable to access the web UI.  On investigation, it seems that the issue was caused by a conflict of versions of ruby and passenger. I'm using an external nginx on the server, as the tail server has other virtual hosts. I have the latest version of passenger installed - 6.0.9. Gitlab latest version comes with ruby version 2.7.2 - but passenger 6.0.9 has no support for that version, it support 2.7.3 instead.

I downgraded passenger to version 6.0.8 - now the passenger_native error is resolved (by direct downloading exact version).  However I'm getting the following error in the log:

```
Could not spawn process for application /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails:
A timeout occurred while starting a preloader process.
```

There's not much more info.  There is one question I found on SO from years ago - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979825/gitlab-setup-could-not-spawn-process-for-application-opt-gitlab-embedded-servic) - with the same error - but it's not solved.  I'm in no position to install/run docker on the server.

How can I get gitlab UI to show?

Note: this is cross-posted to ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1066976/cannot-access-gitlab-web-ui-after-upgrading-omnibus-to-14-12).

Comment: This looks like a perfect question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @NicoHaase It is posted there as well